# java debug interface:get value of ObjectReference

Tags: debugging, jdi

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to use non-static field with ReferenceType
```

i trace the code which like below:

```
  if(!var5.isStatic()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attempt to use non-static field with ReferenceType");
        }
```

and my Class is:

```
public class App {
private String version;
private int system;}
```

i know is not static,but i want to get the value of version,but the type of value is com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference,so how could i get the value of version?

Comment: `var5.referenceType().getValue(var5.referenceType().fieldByName("version"))` should works

Comment: THX for your answer。 it is still not work ,but i find out this can be done by codes:List<ObjectReference> ors=rt.instances(0l);ors.get(0).getValue(field);